# Are data in temporary table in stored procedure of mysql not cleared automatically?

Tags: mysql

Using temporary table in stored procedure of mysql, looks like that data  in temporary table are added any procedure calling without clearing the data :

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS sp_fillUserTasksReport;

create procedure sp_fillUserTasksReport(
    OUT out_returnCode bigint unsigned
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE userId int unsigned;
    DECLARE userName varchar(100);
    DECLARE userEmail varchar(100);
    DECLARE activeTasksCount int unsigned;
    DECLARE completedTasksCount int unsigned;
    DECLARE hasActiveTeamLeadTasks int unsigned;
    DECLARE taskJson json;

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE usersCursor cursor
        for SELECT users.id, users.name, users.email
            FROM users
            ORDER BY users.id;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempUserTasksReport
    (
        user_id                    bigint unsigned,
        user_name                  varchar(100),
        user_email                 varchar(100),
        active_tasks_count         int unsigned,
        completed_tasks_count      int unsigned,
        has_active_team_lead_tasks int unsigned,
        assigned_tasks             json DEFAULT NULL
    );

    -- DELETE FROM tempUserTasksReport;
    -- I HAD TO UNCOMMENT ROW ABOVE TO CLEAR DATA - BUT THAT SEEMS not very good decision

    SET out_returnCode := 0;

    open usersCursor;
    usersLoop:
    loop
        -- get all children of in_taskId and check them
        fetch usersCursor into userId, userName, userEmail;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE usersLoop;
        END IF;

        select count(*)
        into activeTasksCount
        from users
        where userId in (select distinct task_user.user_id
                         from task_user,
                              tasks
                         where tasks.status = 'T'
                           and task_user.task_id = tasks.id);

        select count(*)
        into completedTasksCount
        from users
        where userId in (select distinct task_user.user_id
                         from task_user,
                              tasks
                         where tasks.status = 'D'
                           and task_user.task_id = tasks.id);

        select count(*)
        into hasActiveTeamLeadTasks
        from users
        where userId in (select distinct task_user.user_id
                         from task_user,
                              tasks
                         where tasks.status = 'T'
                           and task_user.task_id = tasks.id
                           and task_user.team_lead = 1);

        SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', task_user.task_id, 'title', tasks.title))
        INTO taskJson
        FROM task_user,
             tasks
        WHERE task_user.user_id = userId
          AND task_user.task_id = tasks.id;

        -- Insert into the temporary table
        INSERT INTO tempUserTasksReport (user_id, user_name, user_email, active_tasks_count, completed_tasks_count,
                                         has_active_team_lead_tasks, assigned_tasks)
        VALUES (userId, userName, userEmail, activeTasksCount, completedTasksCount, hasActiveTeamLeadTasks, taskJson);

        SET out_returnCode := out_returnCode + 1;

    end loop usersLoop;
    close usersCursor;


    INSERT INTO user_tasks_report (user_id, user_name, user_email, active_tasks, completed_tasks, has_active_team_lead_tasks, assigned_tasks, created_at)
   select user_id, user_name, user_email, active_tasks_count, completed_tasks_count, has_active_team_lead_tasks, assigned_tasks, NOW() from tempUserTasksReport;

END;
```

Not sure, if deleting the table data in the beginning of the procedure is good decision ?

```
8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Temporary tables are dropped when the database connection is closed. However, if the connection is kept open and reused, then the temporary tables stay around.

Comment: I think your code is overcomplicated and there is no need for the temporary table. You could use conditional aggregation (there are tons of examples on SO) to generate the resultset you want with a single sql statement that you can use in the final insert into statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) explain how temporary tables work.

> You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. A TEMPORARY table is visible only within the current session, and is dropped automatically when the session is closed. This means that two different sessions can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of the same name. (The existing table is hidden until the temporary table is dropped.)

A session is a connection, so you would need to close the connection for mysql to remove the table. Or alternatively, as you mentioned, to drop the table if it exists at the start of the script if the connection is reused.

Comment: Could you please explain what are "current session" and "different sessions" at debug stage, when I run call from dbeaver and at real work when in php app procedures are called from php side with logged user session ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo As stated in the answer _"A session is a connection"_. When testing in DBeaver, each execution of the sproc will be reusing the existing database connection (session). In the context of your PHP scripts, as soon as the script finishes executing the connection to the db server is closed (unless you are using persistent connections) and the temporary table is deleted. You could add a drop statement to the end of your sproc so the temporary table is explicitly dropped when done with.

Comment: @PetroGromovo The connection always acts as single thread. it is not possible that existing temptable is used by any other, concurrent, process. So you may unconditionally drop it (if exists) then create it with the structure which you need. But you must understand that if you use nested stored procedures than it is possible that this temptable was created in outer procedure - in this case the temptable recreation will effect the outer procedure flow. For to avoid this you must use temptable name which is unique over your SPs - for example, use SP name as temptable name prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Augusto has already answered your question about the lifespan of a temporary table, so this addresses the other issues with your current approach.

You should steer clear of the very old comma separated tables list in favour of the more explicit join syntax.

As already pointed out by Shadow in the comments, you appear to be overcomplicating things. Furthermore, unless I am completing misunderstanding what is going on, your count queries are incorrect.

For each user, your are counting all users if current `userId` is in the subquery result. Let's take your first count query  as an example:

```sql
select count(*)
into activeTasksCount
from users
where userId in (select distinct task_user.user_id
                  from task_user,
                       tasks
                  where tasks.status = 'T'
                    and task_user.task_id = tasks.id);
```

The outer query is assigning the count of all users to the variable `activeTasksCount` if `userId` (current loop iteration `userId` var) has at least 1 active task. Surely, you want the count of active tasks assigned to `userId`?

```sql
select count(*)
into activeTasksCount
from task_user tu
join tasks t on tu.task_id = t.id
where t.status = 'T'
and tu.user_id = userId;
```

As Shadow pointed out, your separate count queries can be combined using conditional aggregation, something like:

```sql
SELECT
    u.id AS userID, u.name AS userName, u.email AS userEmail,
    SUM(t.status = 'T') AS activeTasksCount,
    SUM(t.status = 'D') AS completedTasksCount,
    SUM(t.status = 'T' AND tu.team_lead = 1) AS hasActiveTeamLeadTasks,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', t.id, 'title', t.title)) AS taskJson
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN task_user tu ON u.id = tu.user_id
LEFT JOIN tasks t ON tu.task_id = t.id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.id;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/viOcXX3A).

Comment: thanks for your master class.
Could you please to propose for me several tasks to make better my raw sql habits?
The thing is that last years I use php/laravel with eloquent and somewhat lost my raw sql habits.
Want to resume them now...

Comment: It's just practice. ORMs have their uses but should not be used for everything!